# How to model hand-sorted ToDo list in DynamoDb?

Tags: database-design, nosql, amazon-dynamodb, data-modeling

The sorting works just as your every-day todo app, where the user sets the order of items by hand.

My thoughts so far:

If we use a list in a single Dynamo record to store the data, sorting is simple, however:

- Updating an item means updating the whole list of items.
- The list size is bound to 400KB

If we save each item as a record in DynamoDb, we'll need to specify a "weight" value every time we sort, or save an item, which can cause race conditions. One that comes to mind is when storing new item:

- read the latest item index -Answer: 21
- (write an item at index 21, but from a different, concurrent procedure)
- write new item at index 21. -Error: 21 is taken

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**SEE ALTERNATE SOLUTION BELOW** - responding to OP comment asking to maintain list order in the index.

#### One solution

1. Partition your table by list
2. Store each list item as a separate item
3. Store a separate `sortOrder` item with a version number

**Pros:**

- The `sortOrder` item can act as a list lock (via the version number), solving your race condition
- Resorting a list only requires updating one item (the `sortOrder` item)
- Inserting or appending a new item to your list only required updating two items (the new item, and the `sortOrder` item)

**Cons:**

- When querying a list's items, they will not be returned in the correct sort order. You'll need to use the `order` attribute of the `sortOrder` item to sort the returned items each time.

This sorting could be done server side (e.g. in a lambda function prior to returning the query results to your client) or client side (in your frontend code). Sorting a relatively short list is pretty performant and your use case sounds like this would probably not cause a problem. You should consider your expected access patterns and performance needs though.

**Example table:**

```
partion key | sort key    | version | order                    | item_details
list#1      | sortOrder   | 2       | [item#UUID1, item#UUID2]
list#1      | item#UUID1  |         |                          | foo
list#1      | item#UUID2  |         |                          | bar
list#2      | sortOrder   | 1       | [item#UUID3]
list#2      | item#UUID3  |         |                          | baz
```

**To CREATE (insert) a new item:**

- `get_item` the list's `sortOrder` item
- `put_item` the new item
- `update_item` the `sortOrder` with an incremented version and new `order` attribute, conditional on the expected version number still being there
- If the condition fails (because another client changed the list since you did your original `get_item`) you can delete the new item you inserted and then start over.

**To READ (list) the items in a list**

- `query` all items in a list, including the `sortOrder`
- sort the `item`s using the `sortOrder` `order` attribute
- Note: it's possible that another client added an item that hasn't updated the `sortOrder` yet. Depending on your needs, you could ignore the new item or you could retry until the items in `order` match the actual items returned

**To UPDATE an item in a list**

- `update_item` on the item

**To DELETE an item in a list**

- `get_item` the list's `sortOrder` item
- `update_item` the `sortOrder` with an incremented version and new `order` attribute, conditional on the expected version number still being there
- `delete_item` the item to be deleted

**To SORT an existing list**

- `update_item` the `sortOrder` item, conditional on the expected `version`. The expected `version` would have been from the last time the client queried the list items

#### A different approach: TransactWriteItems

If it's important that the items are stored in sorted order, you can leverage `TransactWriteItems` which will allow you to batch write up to 25 items in a single transaction. Provided your to-do lists don't exceed 25 items, this would be a simpler solution with more performant list reads at the expense of less performant inserts and sorts. The 25 item limit is the main issue with this one.

### ALTERNATE SOLUTION

Per your comment, another solution is to sort the list via the sort key. You would still need a lock for each list, but the process will be slightly different.

**Example table:**

```
partition key | sort key | itemID  | version | item_details | TTL    | lock_key
list#1        | lock     |         | 2       |              | 888500 | xyz123
list#1        | 000001   | UUID1   |         | foo
list#1        | 000002   | UUID2   |         | bar
list#2        | lock     |         | 1       |              | 888001 | abc456
list#2        | 000001   | UUID3   |         | baz
```

**To acquire the lock** for a list, the client should:

- update:

  - the `TTL` to now + an interval (e.g. 10 seconds)
  - the `lock_key` (to a random string provided by the client)
  - increment the `version` number
- conditional upon:

  - the `TTL` < now (i.e. any previous lock has expired)

**To refresh a lock** already acquired by a client (i.e. if the 10 second limit is approaching):

- update:

  - the `TTL` to now + an interval (e.g. another 10 seconds)
  - increment the `version`
- conditional upon:

  - the `lock_key` == expected `lock_key` (i.e. it didn't expire and be acquired by another client)

The lock will need to be acquired when inserting or appending items, or updating the sort order. If you're just updating the other (non-sort key) attribute(s) of an item, you won't necessarily need the lock.

If you're reading the list, you can optimistically query without acquiring the lock, but you should read the lock before and after to make sure it hasn't been acquired in the meantime, as that could result in an inconsistent list and so you would in that case retry. This is the reason for the `version` attribute on the `lock`.

So:

**When inserting, appending or changing the sort order:**

- acquire the list's lock
- write the item(s), including updating the new sort key for each item being moved
- refresh the list's lock if you need more time

**When reading**

- read the lock
- if TTL > now

  - an update is in progress so wait until after TTL and retry
- else if TTL < now:

  - read list items (i.e. query)
  - read lock again. If version has changed, then queried items may not be consistent so start over. If it has not changed, then client can trust the returned results were consistent.

The problem with using locks are that while a list is being updated, other clients won't be able to read consistently. Depending on your use case this might be acceptable. If not, you could create a cache layer that is transactionally consistent. The implementation of a cache probably goes beyond the scope of your question though :)

All of this assumes your to-do lists are not limited to 25 items, otherwise you can use `TransactWriteItems` as mentioned.

Comment: I really appreciate your effort. My first hunch, however, is that I'm really uncomfortable having the two sources of truth. I'm trying to think of a way to keep the sorting information in the index itself.

Comment: @DanielBirowskyPopeski that's fair enough. Based on that I've provided an alternate solution that orders each list natively by sort key instead. The hard part is being able to write transactionally and still allowing other clients to consistently read. How far you need to take the engineering (i.e. considering read replicas / caching) will depend on how chatty the writes will be, and how concurrent your reads will be. This has been a fun problem! I hope this update helps.

Comment: Again, really appreciate your attention (an upvote overdue). The problem I see in your latest suggestion is when item in index 100 is moved to index 10. We would need to update indexes of the 90 items in between. I think, ideally, we would change only the sort key of the item that moved. It should be possible. The client would know the index of the item before the new index so the new index would be something like "sub-increasing" the index of the previous item. Example, for index "K", next index would be "K0" maybe we can use the whole Unicode table for this?

Comment: I see what you're saying, and I agree that it's not great to have to reindex the whole list when you insert near the top. If you try your strategy, you'll need to know the element before and after to make sure you don't overwrite the one after. To maximise the inserts you can do you can split the difference, but you'll quickly run out of room if you keep inserting at the same spot. If your lists aren't super long then I think the first solution is worth considering again, as inserting and resorting are very efficient, and the lock will keep everything consistent.